# How to collapse a responsive CSS grid to 2 columns instead of 1?

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS grid setup which works perfectly, it displays 6 columns when viewed on a desktop and collapses to 1 when viewed on a mobile device.

However, I'd like it to collapse to 2 columns rather than 1 when viewed on a mobile device, I can't work out what I have to change to do this.

```css
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
        text-align: center;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

//*  GRID OF SIX  */
.span_6_of_6 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span_5_of_6 {
    width: 83.06%;
}

.span_4_of_6 {
    width: 66.13%;
}

.span_3_of_6 {
    width: 49.2%;
}

.span_2_of_6 {
    width: 32.26%;
}

.span_1_of_6 {
    width: 15.33%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    .span_1_of_6, .span_2_of_6, .span_3_of_6, .span_4_of_6, .span_5_of_6, .span_6_of_6 { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
<span style="font-size:35px;"><i class="fas fa-wifi"></i></span><br />Wifi
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
<span style="font-size:35px;"><i class="fas fa-tv"></i></span><br />Smart TV With Freeview
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
<img width="75px" src="https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c529.png"></img><br />Netflix
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
<img width="75px" src="https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c548.png"></img><br />YouTube
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
<img width="50px" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2047/2047381.svg"></img><br />Towels
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
<img width="50px" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/125/125669.svg"></img><br />Hair Dryer
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unrelated - you have invalid HTML; `<img>` elements are self-closing. They end with `/>`, not `></img>`.

Comment: I recommend you to give a try to css grids, these kind of requirements are very easy to solve with  [Grids](https://learncssgrid.com/).

Comment: You've tagged your question as [css-grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), yet I see no use of it in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width: 50%` should do the trick https://jsfiddle.net/x52z9hk6/

```
/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    .span_1_of_6, .span_2_of_6, .span_3_of_6, .span_4_of_6, .span_5_of_6, .span_6_of_6 { width: 50%; }
}
```

media tag is triggered when `480px` limit is reached, `width: 100%` makes it full row, `width: 50%` - half and so on

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that! I'm extremely new to this so I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5):

Actually using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

```css
/*  SECTIONS  */

.section {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  /*6 Colum Grid*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}


/*  GO Two Colum BELOW 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .section {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section group">
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    <span style="font-size:35px;"><i class="fas fa-wifi"></i></span><br />Wifi
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    <span style="font-size:35px;"><i class="fas fa-tv"></i></span><br />Smart TV With Freeview
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    <img width="75px" src="https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c529.png"><br />Netflix
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    <img width="75px" src="https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c548.png"><br />YouTube
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    <img width="50px" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2047/2047381.svg"><br />Towels
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    <img width="50px" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/125/125669.svg"><br />Hair Dryer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm extremely new to this so still learning!